# Jquery, can not delete newly created li elements

Tags: jquery

As a uni project i am making a shopping cart, so far you can add products to the cart, and if you refresh the page, you can delete items from the cart.

But when the item is added to the basket, you can not delete it from the cart without first refreshing the browser. Why is that?

this is my delete item form cart function

```
    $('.del').on("click",function(){
    var id= this.id;
    var productId = $('#productId-'+id).text();
    var productPrice = $('#price-'+id).text();
    var total = $('#total').text();
    var newPrice = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(productPrice)).toFixed(2);
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    cartSize--;

    $('#total').html(newPrice);     
    $("#cart-"+id).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/del.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#added-'+productId).fadeOut('Fast');
            $('#product-'+productId).delay(600).fadeIn('Fast');

            if(cartSize == 0){
                $('#noItems').fadeIn('Fast');
                $('#mainCart').fadeOut('Fast');     
            }
        }
    });
    return false;   

});
```

});

and heres my add to cart function:

```
     $('.addToCart').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var price = parseFloat($('#priceAdd-'+id).val()).toFixed(2);;
    var name = $('#name-'+id).val();
    var total =(parseFloat($('#total').text())+parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
    cartSize++;

    $('#product-'+id).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#added-'+id).delay(500).fadeIn('fast');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'resources/addToCart.php',
        data: { itemId: id , name: name, price: price},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("ol").append(html).slideDown("slow");
            $('#noItems').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#total').html(total);
            $('#mainCart').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `.live()` because: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated."

You want to use `.on()`

```
$('#myListItems').on("click", ".del" ,function(e) {
   $(e.target).remove()
});
```

[jQuery's on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.on()` so that it applies to future elements, as you would have with the *deprecated* `.live()` function.

N.B. .on() is not simply an alias of .live(), the syntax is different.

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function(){...});
```

I've used document there, but it's better that you select an element that exists as a closer parent of the ones you're creating dynamically, e.g.

```
$('#basket').on('click', '.del', function(){...});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/